# Compiler Explorer Assembly Output for C, C++ and D (dlang)

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, d, compiler-explorer

When using Compiler Explorer (https://godbolt.org/) to compare assembly output of simple programs, why D language assembly output is so long compared to C or C++ output. The simple square function output is the same for C, C++, and D, but the D output has additional lines that are not highlighted when hovering over the square function in the source code.

- What are these additional lines?
- How I can remove these lines from being generated?

Let's say I have https://godbolt.org/z/64EsWo5Ke a template function both in C++ and D, the Intel asm output for D is 29309 lines long, while the C++ Intel asm output is 73 lines only.

Comment: When you open the https://godbolt.org/ link, the square function is already there. You just need to change the languages from C++ to C or D.

Comment: the default output is unoptimized. Comparing those unoptimized code is pointless

Comment: I am doing this for research purpose, comparing programming languages with their compilation time, assembly output, etc.

Comment: Godbolt is unusable on a mobile phone. Please post your code and assembly output in the question as code-formatted text.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions asking about performance/benchmarking without any optimizing options enabled are nonsensical. Please edit the question to use code with optimizer enabled in all used languages...

Comment: @m.tariqsiddiqui Comparing assembly output is very nice and all, but there is much more in a program than that. For example if you compile your C++ code and examine it using a decompiler (like cutter or ghidra) you will find that it is also littered with "useless" code, like libc_start_main and others. Will it run w/o this? No but it is not technically your intended code so it overhead.

Comment: @m.tariqsiddiqui [tag:compiler-explorer] **has nothing to do with this question**. It's just a tool that runs compilers and prints the output. The instructions you see are from the compilers and you're comparing compilers and you can see the same thing if you run those compilers locally. You must not tag the irrelevant things here. Besides if you ask about instructions then a relevant architecture is necessary. Almost all compilers can output instructions in different architectures, not only x86

Comment: The D code is statically linked by default. I believe that is why you see such a long output.

Comment: @DejanLekic: It's asm output from the compiler, not disassembly, but perhaps dmd is compiling the standard library code from headers?  https://godbolt.org/z/oKn7aro7o shows that if you remove the main and just define the DoubleIt function, the output is much more compact.  (Although the function doesn't appear at all, I guess because it's a template not instantiated.)  I also notice the Godbolt "library functions" filter is grayed out for D, but not C++.  Very likely compiler-explorer has better filtering for the most common languages that it supported first, like C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the codes in question:
For D:

```
int example.square(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], edi
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbp - 4]
        imul    eax, dword ptr [rbp - 4]
        pop     rbp
        ret

ldc.register_dso:
        sub     rsp, 40
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], 1
        lea     rax, [rip + ldc.dso_slot]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 16], rax
        lea     rax, [rip + __start___minfo]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 24], rax
        lea     rax, [rip + __stop___minfo]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 32], rax
        lea     rax, [rsp + 8]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    _d_dso_registry@PLT
        add     rsp, 40
        ret

example.__ModuleInfo:
        .long   2147483652
        .long   0
        .asciz  "example"

example.__moduleRef:
        .quad   example.__ModuleInfo

ldc.dso_slot:
        .quad   0
```

C/C++:

```
square(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        imul    eax, eax
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

As you can see the actual implementation in assembly is very similar (almost identical). The program constructs the stack frame:

```
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
```

Takes the argument and multiplies it with itself leaving it in the return value (`eax` register):

```
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], edi
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbp - 4]
        imul    eax, dword ptr [rbp - 4]
```

in D and

```
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        imul    eax, eax
```

in C++/C, and then deconstructs stack frame and returns:

```
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Now I don't claim to know what the D compiler is doing, but I assume the rest of the code is so that this piece of compiled code can work well with other D code. Basically metadata and other fun stuff. I assume this because nowhere does our function use any of the defined symbols nor do the other function call square. This code is therefore probably to do something with inclusion into other D programs, or the like, and therefore you might not be able to/should not remove it.

In the case of your second example, most of the code is the output library implemented. [Using only the function defined](https://godbolt.org/z/ETfE97Es3) it is actually 66 lines long. While still longer than the equivalent 22 lines of C++ generated assembly it is not several thousand.

Edit:

As I explained in a comment would recommend to analyse the output binaries with something like Cutter or Ghidra, which give you a more complete picture of what is actually produced in a binary, because I can tell you that even in 'shorter' C++ code you will find a lot of function calls such as `_entry` before getting to main.

Comment: C and C++ on Linux with glibc use the same CRT startup code to get from `_start` to `main`.  That involves having `_start` pass the address of `main` to `__libc_start_main`, for it to run libc startup code and then do an indirect call to main.  (`__libc_start_main` is *in* libc, not in your executable itself unless you statically link).

Comment: @Peter Cordes Oh yeah sorry my bad. I was actually talking about the _entry func I am just stupid

Comment: What systems use `_entry`?`  On Linux (which the compilers on Godbolt target), the ELF entry point is normally called `_start`.